# Handle Change of FormControl React

Tags: reactjs, onchange, form-control

Hey so I have a text box/FormControl that's supposed to update a field in a json in this.state. I was wondering if there was a better way to do onChange?

```
<FormControl 
  type='text' 
  placeholder='enter' 
  defaultValue={this.state.form.name}
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}
/>
</FormGroup>
```

`

```
handleChange(change, event) {
    var toChange = this.state.form;
    toChange[change] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({form: toChange});
  }
```

Comment: What is it that you'd like to improve about the event handler? It looks pretty ok. One thing you might want to consider though, is to not mutate the state. You could do something like `this.setState({form: {...this.state.form, [change]: event.target.value}})`. That will be necessary if you implement `shouldComponentUpdate` at some point for performance reasons.

Comment: Something like that! Thanks

Comment: I get unexpected token on the first . in ...

Comment: What does your compile config file look like (for webpack or whatever), the ... spread syntax is still stage-0 I think which may be why it is dying.

Answer (score 17):

Optimise the handleChange method as below. (replace 'username' with the fieldname you like...)

```
<FormControl 
  type='text'
  name='username' 
  placeholder='enter' 
  defaultValue={this.state.form.username}
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
/>
</FormGroup>

handleChange(event) {
    let fieldName = event.target.name;
    let fleldVal = event.target.value;
    this.setState({form: {...this.state.form, [fieldName]: fleldVal}})
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

If your function is relatively simple you can simplify further,

```
onChange = { (event) => { this.myValue = event.target.value } }
```

or if you're passing up the `props` hierarchy, e.g.

```
onChange = { (event) => { this.props.onMyFunc(event.target.value) } }
```